# TypeError: Cannot convert BigInt to number, js engine: hermes - noble-secp256k1 package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, bigint

I have a react native app, I am trying to use the package `noble-secp256k1`. I need this in order to generate a key pair (private and public key) `secp.getPublicKey(secp.utils.randomPrivateKey())`, however, just by having this package installed, when I run `react-native run-ios` I am getting this error and the app crashes.

```
TypeError: Cannot convert BigInt to number, js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 10): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient.
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 10): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient.
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
Process terminated. Press <enter> to close the window
```

I cannot find a way to fix this, it looks like react native does not support bigint's ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this `{unstable_transformProfile: 'hermes-stable'}` to your preset.

`const presets = [["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset", {unstable_transformProfile: 'hermes-stable'}]];`